# What's the purpose of adding a parallel impedance to a relay circuit?

Tags: relay, mains

This is the relay section of a PIR Sensor I have taken apart.:

[image]

L_FUSED is 240VAC, and the relay is intended to turn on a light bulb from "OUT" (standard edison screw), so it could be incandescent, fluorescent, or LED.

What is the purpose of the designer adding an impedance parallel to the light bulb load, which is purely resistive? My thought is that in case there is no load connected, switching the relay on may cause arcing if there is no impedance connected - however I'm not sure.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't purely resistive - it's mainly reactive due to the 100nF capacitor. At (say) 50Hz, 100nF will have an impedance (reactance) of nearly 32kohms.

The resistor is there to absorb any spikes that may otherwise cause damage to the relay contact. It's called a snubber circuit and is often seen in parallel with contacts too.

A lightbulb will be purely resistive but there could be a reason in the designer's mind that maybe a motor could be connected and this could cause inductive kick-back voltages of thousands of volts.

Comment: Another relay is probably more likely than a motor, with just as much justification for the snubber.